# How to set up and access a database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I've almost made an app that works like a kind of item viewer - you press on an entry in a listview and it takes you to a detail page for that entry. Super simple.

The only thing is that I stored all my data in the creation of these entries, and I see that being extremely inefficient. I have tried all day to work out how to make a database but it seems unnecessarily difficult.

Am I going the wrong way about this? I just want to have a pre-populated set of data from which the app can draw from - it shouldn't be this hard. I've programmed in c++ and python a little in the past and figured this would be an extremely simple project to begin with.

I'm currently trying to get ExternalSQLiteOpenHelper to work for me - but it's proving extremely difficult to even just access a corresponding row of the database given its id or anything.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a simple-to-use database, try to look at Firebase by Google. For android app, if you are using Android Studio, it is very easy to set up and add your project to link with Firebase.

Here is the link to get started with: [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)

After adding your project to Firebase, you can use Firebase Realtime Database feature and for listview, you can use FirebaseUI library for that.

Comment: Thanks - I'll take a look